# Launching to google map directly without prompt

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I am trying to launch google map with the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+address));
startActivity(intent);
```

My intent is to launch directly to Google Map at the section where you choose the route. However, on some phones, they suggest different apps beside Google Map to launch. How can I go around this prompt? If the users choose a different app it might mess up my intention (to launch navigation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + address));
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",
            "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know I can use setClassName to launch a specific app for intent. On the other hand, do you know how I can suggest to open my app when users click on an "address"?